# Custom Dart repositories?

Tags: dart, dependency-management

Pub is a great tool for managing dependencies of Dart projects. I wonder if there's any tool available which allows us to create in-house repositories and setup mirrors for public dependencies similarly how Maven repository managers do it (Nexus, Archiva, etc.)

I've searched the net and it seems that the source of the Pub repository site is not publicly available. Maybe the dependency lookup in the current Pub client is hardwired to the central Pub repository anyway.

Comment: You can set direct dependencies on Git repositories on a local network server if you want. That's not exactly what you asked, but it's a start.

Comment: As Justin mentioned its not exactly designed for local hosting, but enough is there you could host your own pub server on app engine. Some tweeks are needed to get the cloud storage and application keys figured out. I was able host a pub app engine project in little under 30 mins using that code base. http://staging-dart-client-apis.appspot.com/ Down side with out billing information and cloud storage account, I cant actually store packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source for the Pub server at pub.dartlang.org is available on github: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang

It's a Python App Engine app, so it's not exactly designed to be run locally, but it's a starting point.

Pub also does support alternate pub repositories. See: http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pubspec.html#dependencies